# Setting up a new page name in Adobe Analytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

I created a new page on my website and I want to define this page name in Omniture to track more easyly.

Could somebody help me on my issue?

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 1):

You can give any new page a "friendly" name by assigning a value to the pageName variable.

```
s.pageName = "My Friendly Page Name"
```

It is also common to set the pageName dynamically using server-side code or even client-side JavaScript`

```
s.pageName = $my_var
```

As a side note, if the pageName variable does not contain a value, Adobe Analytics will automatically pass the URL in the Most Popular Pages reports.

Hope this helps.